# How to set maxSdkVersion for 1.5 apps

Tags: android, android-manifest

I do have an app that should only be visible in the market for Android 1.5 and 1.6 devices. So I thought I compile for SDK version 3 and set

```
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="3" maxSdkVersion="4" />
```

But it seems not to be so easy. I get an error saying

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'maxSdkVersion' in package 'android'
```

How am I supposed to achieve that my app is only visible for sdk version 3 and 4 devices?
Just to clarify: i have a second version of the app in the market for all devices with android >2.0 because it makes use of the `AccountManager`. The new version doesn't make use of it since it's not supported in 1.5 and 1.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting that error because you are developing against the 1.5 SDK instead of 1.6.

To test it on the 1.5 Emulator you have to [manually install the apk.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#move)

Comment: yes, if i set project target sdk to 1.6 it works fine. but then i can't launch it anymore in 1.5 emulator because it sais that minSdkVersion is smaller then targetSdkVersion :(
How can i test my app in 1.5 emulator then? and should i just ignore the warning eclipse gives me in the manifest file then?

Comment: I just found out the switch in eclipse where i can force the 1.5 emulator to start the app even when it's smaller then the targetSdkVersion. Seems to work perfectly. Thx :)
Now it looks like this:
Eclipse Project Target SDK: 1.6
<uses-sdk minSdkVersion="3" maxSdkVersion="4" />